# Split contentable paragraph where is cursor - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have contenteditable div:

```
<div id="formatted" contenteditable="true">
    <p>
       Here is some <b>content</b> warpped in paragraph.
    </p>
</div>

<input id="spliter" type="submit" value="spliter">
```

I want to set up cursor somewhere in pharagraph, for example after word "wrapped", then click on input "spliter" and after that paragraph need to split on two paragraphs like this:

```
 <div id="formated" contenteditable="true">
    <p>
       Here is some <b>content</b> 
    </p>
    <p>
       wrapped in paragraph.
    </p>
 </div>
```

I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("spliter").click(function(){
        var s = window.getSelection();
        s.modify('extend','backward','paragraph');        
        var before = s.toString(); //here is text before cursor

        s.modify('extend','forward','paragraph');
        var after = s.toString(); //here is text after cursor
    });
});
```

In variable before I have text before cursor "Here is some content" 
and in variable after I have text after cursor "wrapped in paragraph.",
so I can create two new paragraphs and replace with old.

But problem is that I need these b tags also, because with this "toString()" method I am getting only text but I need also html. Html allowed in this paragraphs is : 'b', 'em', 'i', 'strong', 'u', 'p', 'ul', 'li', 'ol'.

Any idea how to get html or another way to do this???

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this. I am not sure if it works on all browser though.

```
var elem = document.createElement("div");
if (s.rangeCount) elem.appendChild(s.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents());
before = elem.innerHTML;
```